# Triple intergration find the moment of inertia of a cylinder

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

What is the Moment of Inertia of a cylinder of Radius R, length l and mass M when rotated about an axis along the length of the cylinder?

I've had a lot of examples of calculating the Moment of inertia over mainly 2D shapes so I'm finding it difficult to understand where to start. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to know the $\vec{r}$ dependence of the mass density.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wikipedia has a table list of all the moment of inertia for many 3D objects:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks